# Krita won't draw using tablet but with trackpad/mouse

Tags: kde, xubuntu, tablet

I am having a weird problem. With Krita 2 earlier, I was able to paint perfectly well using mouse/trackpad/tablet. However, now with Krita 3 I am not able to draw with my tablet anymore. Mouse and trackpad still work. When I went back to Krita 2 I face the same problem again.
The tablet works fine in GIMP or even in Krita when I use other tools, but the brush. When I hover over the tablet, it shows the brush and when the brush circle width decreases the way it does. However, nothing gets drawn on the canvas. I am running Xubuntu 16.04 and I installed Krita from ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports. I am using a Huion H610 tablet the buttons of which, including that of the stylus, I haven't configured at all. Button 1 of my stylus has now changed from 'left click' to 'pan tool' and button 2 is still functioning as 'right click'. However, the color wheel that comes up now behaves weird. It keeps rotating when I hover on the triangle. These problems weren't there earlier.
Please help!